# iOS in Tableview textfield get value in for loop is not working in ios 7 but its working in iOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have get tableview textfield value  on click on button , I lots of try but i can't able to get value Please help me here is my code its always print null value, this for loop run on
Click On button  but this code is not working in ios 7 simulater but its working with ios 8 Please help me

```
for (int k=0; k< aryModifier.count; k++) {
       // NSLog(@"--%d",i);
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:k inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[self tbl_itemModifier] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UITextField *getTextView = (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:200];

        //for (UIView *subView in cell.subviews)
        for (UIView *subView in cell.contentView.subviews)
        {
            if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            {
                UITextField *txtField = (UITextField *)subView;
                NSLog(@"%@",txtField.text);
            }
        }

        //UITextField *getTextView = (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:i];

        NSLog(@"%@",getTextView.text);
    }
```

and Table Cellforrow at index path

```
UITextField *txt=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 40, 50, 15)];
            txt.text = @"1";
            txt.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            txt.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            txt.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            txt.tag = 200;//indexPath.row;
            txt.delegate = self;
            NSString *str = txt.text;
            [cell addSubview:txt];
```

I try both way but i cant get success . Please help me .........

```
//for (UIView *subView in cell.subviews)
            for (UIView *subView in cell.contentView.subviews)
```

Please give me solution ... 
if you have any demo link please share with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change below line of code:

```
UITextField *getTextView = (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:200];
```

to

```
UITextField *getTextView = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:200];
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the approach you're using:

1. Creating a new control in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is bad practice. Proper MVC would dictate moving that creation to your `UITableViewCell`'s `init` or `initWithCoder:` method. Doing it in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is extremely likely to result in multiple controls being added to a cell as that cell is recycled. That method is really intended only for cell **configuration**, not view hierarchy creation/management.
2. Iterating `UITableViewCell` objects is a bad idea. The reason is that iOS aggressively manages memory consumption when creating `UITableViewCell` instances for display. It recycles cells as often as it can. Therefore, if you have a table view with many cells, only a small portion of them will be available at any given time. You should be using an external data source to provide the data that the table view uses to populate its cells. You should also be using this to grab the data you need, not relying on controls in a `UITableViewCell` for that data.

A few questions for you:
- How are you currently populating your cells? 
- Is there other data that is displayed in the cells, or are they just a scrolling set of `UITextField` instances? 
- Is this basically just a scrollable form?

Assuming (based on the limited evidence provided) that you're trying to implement a form, here are my suggestions:

1. Don't use a `UITableView`. I know it's tempting because it handles the keyboard show/hide well and will (sometimes) provide auto-scrolling to the selected control, but it's really trying to fit a square peg in a round hole. It's not what a `UITableView` is made to do. Instead, learn how to correctly implement forms in a `UIScrollView`. In particular, this become much easier for me when I embraced a "full auto layout implementation" methodology. It's a little bit more complicated to set up initially, but it works much better and makes tasks like yours a lot more logical.
2. If you **must** use a `UITableView`, figure out a way to persist data on-the-fly to a separate data source that is used to populate your `UITableView`. That way, as cells are recycled, you can refresh them with correct data, and when you need to access the entered data, you have no need to iterate `UITableViewCell` instances (which is fairly "expensive" to do).